# What's wrong with "command not found: create-nuxt-app"

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, npx

When I use npx to create a Nuxt.js program

```
PS D:\vue\miniProgram\mt-app> npx create-nuxt-app mt-app
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Slade'
command not found: create-nuxt-app
```

PS. CLI:Windows PowerShell

Comment: I'd guess that there's a space in your username? This is probably npx trying to make a temp folder somewhere under your user folder to install create-nuxt-app so it can run it, but it's getting confused by a space somewhere. But I don't know which path npx uses, or where to suggest looking for this.

Answer (score 4):

> npm install -g create-nuxt-app

> npm create-nuxt-app <app_Name>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have spaces in username. There are [still](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100) [issues](https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/48) [regarding](https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/14) it. You'll need to work around it at the time.

1. Open `C:\Users\Slade with Space\.npmrc`.
2. [Modify](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100#issuecomment-484193572) [locations](https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/14#issuecomment-576182299):

   ```
   prefix=C:\Users\Sladew~1\AppData\Roaming\npm
   cache=C:\Users\Sladew~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

   globalconfig=C:\Users\Sladew~1\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
   init-module=C:\Users\Sladew~1\.npm-init.js
   tmp=C:\Users\Sladew~1\AppData\Local\Temp
   userconfig=C:\Users\Sladew~1\.npmrc
   globalignorefile=C:\Users\Sladew~1\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmignore
   ```

   I suppose many of them may be omitted, but important part here is setting of `prefix` and `cache`: if you intend to have username with spaces, it's no problem in referring to it as `Sladew~1` (according to the results of `dir /x`).

Comment: It's usually six characters and ~1, so your example might be Sladew~1. But you can see this in a command prompt with `dir /x`.

Comment: @Rup thanks for the notice, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change npm temp cache directory:

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```